# Getting rating value from dynamic android ratingbar

Tags: android

Due to display of more than 5 stars, I am creating a `RatingBar` dynamically and assigning it to an alert-dialog. Here is the code:

```
rater
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //How to get the rating value here

    });
rater.setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", null);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View final layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ratinglayout,null);
rater.setView(layout);
//rater.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ratinglayout, null));
rater.show();
```

The XML-layout for `RatingBar` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingStars"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I get the rating value inside the OK handler of alert dialog? 
I have trie the following:

```
RatingBar rating = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingStars);
```

But I get a null pointer exception warning when I do this. Therefore, the question is how to get the rating value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
float rating = ((RatingBar)layout.findViewById(R.id.ratingStars)).getRating();
```

use this inside your ok click handler. See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#getRating%28%29)

You are trying to in walk the `findViewById` of the `Activity` I think that is why it is returning null.

Comment: rater is an AlertDialog.Builder and if I try your code, I am getting an findViewById(int) is undefined for type AlertDialog.Builder error

Comment: It works but layout has to be declared final, I have modified my own code to reflect it.Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

```
 private void showDialog() 
 {

final AlertDialog.Builder popdialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final RatingBar rating=new RatingBar(this);
popdialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
popdialog.setTitle("Give us Rattings");
  popdialog.setView(rating);
   rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() 
{

@Override
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar arg0, float arg1, boolean arg2) {

    ratevale=arg1;
}
});
```